# How to find out address in binary file (like IDA) with python code only?

Tags: ida, binary-analysis, python, address, offset

I have binary  for example https://github.com/andrew-d/static-binaries/blob/master/binaries/linux/x86_64/nmap that I open with IDA , and search some data that I want to find without open IDA ,only with python code

1) How to find what is the address of this series of bytes :`48 8B 45 A8 48 8D 1C 02 48 8B 45 C8` ? , the result need to be `0x6B0C67`

2)How to find out the 12 bytes that in address `0x6B0C67` ? the result need to be `48 8B 45 A8 48 8D 1C 02 48 8B 45 C8` .

3) How to find which address call to specific string? for example `i + 1 == features[i].index` that locate in `0x6FC272` ?  the result need to be `0x4022F6`

How can I find all of this without open Ida? only with python/c code?

thanks

Comment: Hy am using Python RegEx . "There is error. Traceback (most recent call last): File "F:\PYTHON\Find hexadecimal offset of certain bytes in binary\test3.py", line 6, in <module> pat = re.search("\x48\x8b\x45\xa8\x48\x8d\x1c\x02\x48\x8b\x45\xc8",dat) File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\re.py", line 200, in search return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object" pls anyone help to identifi my mistake.Thanks! ###code import re import binascii fin = open(input('Enter filename with extension: ') , "rb") dat = fi

Answer (score 1):

you mean you want to search for a hex pattern in an arbitrary file  using your own code either in python or c ?

have you considered using regex or grep to satisfy your needs ?

there are certain things you should be aware of
1) file offsets will not be equal to virtual offsets
2) even if you manage to map the file you may have to deal with aslr
2) you need to brush up your understanding of RVA ,VA , File Offset,File Alignment Versus Section Alignment etc

here is a sample grep demo (notice the similarity in the last 5 bytes )

```
:\>grep  -obaP "\x48\x8b\x45\xa8\x48\x8d\x1c\x02\x48\x8b\x45\xc8" nmap
2821223:H<E"H?∟☻H<EE

:\>printf "%x\n" 2821223
2b0c67
```

or python demo
source

```
D:\>cat nmap.py
import re
fin = open("d:/nmap" , "rb")
dat = fin.read()
fin.close()
pat = re.search("\x48\x8b\x45\xa8\x48\x8d\x1c\x02\x48\x8b\x45\xc8",dat)
offset = hex(pat.start())
print (offset)
```

result

```
D:\>python nmap.py
0x2b0c67
```

now that you know how to find offset you can use any hex editor to print the bytes

here is an xxd demo

```
D:\>xxd -l 32 -g 1 -s 0x2b0c67 nmap
02b0c67: 48 8b 45 a8 48 8d 1c 02 48 8b 45 c8 48 89 c7 e8  H.E.H...H.E.H...
02b0c77: a3 d7 ff ff 48 89 c2 48 8b 45 c0 48 01 d0 48 39  ....H..H.E.H..H9
```

you can simply use binascii to print the bytes at an offset in python as below

```
D:\>type nmap.py
import re
import binascii
fin = open("d:/nmap" , "rb")
dat = fin.read()
pat = re.search("\x48\x8b\x45\xa8\x48\x8d\x1c\x02\x48\x8b\x45\xc8",dat)
offset = hex(pat.start())
print (offset)
print ( binascii.hexlify(dat[pat.start():pat.start()+16]))
fin.close()
D:\>


D:\>python nmap.py
0x2b0c67
488b45a8488d1c02488b45c84889c7e8
```

Comment: I know what is RVA,VA , I want get the addres , with your code I get `2b0c67` that the file offset of `48 8B 45 A8 48 8D 1C 02 48 8B 45 C8` but I looking to get `0x6B0C67` that ImageBase(0x400000) + `2b0c67` , so maybe I need to ask , how can I get with python the  ImageBase address ?    by thw way, do you know how to answer on question 3 ?

Comment: ImageBase is hardcoded in elf header ProgramHeader->p_vaddr  i didnt understand what is your third question  what do you mean by call to specific string i dont know

Comment: when you open this binary in IDA you can find all the string the contain in binary, and each string you can check which address call to this string...

Comment: strings are not called . functions are called :( do you mean xrefs to the strings ? like int  compare(char * blah , char *foo)  where blah and foo are strings and these will have xrefs to them from this function compare  no doing that is not trivial from your own code unless you can write your own disassembler

Comment: 1) what is the easy way to get `ProgramHeader->p_vadd` from elf file  with python ? 2) yes I mean xrefs .... thanks